# Edmx need Primary_Key?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, primary-key, edmx

Its a problem While Creating Edmx in .net that on creating Edmx of DataBase only those Tables and views are added who had a primary key.
This problem resolved easily but just making a column primary key in Table or View but i didn't got the actual reason why it is necessary??
Can anyone please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: It's used to keep track of an object when you perform updates (or deletions for that matter), it's how EF _identifies_ the object.

Comment: okkk @BenjaminGruenbaum I got it Thats a silly question but i never know the reason

Comment: That's not a silly question at all, I'd upvote it if I wasn't past the daily voting limit. I'm waiting for some interesting answers from people who know the architecture better than me (I just read that in a blog post a while ago).

Comment: A **primary key** is the way that each row in your data table is **uniquely** and **efficiently** identified. Each "real" table always **ought to have** a primary key anyway - it's a well-known, well-accepted best practice. Don't fight it - embrace it!

Comment: yes i know that every real table had a primary key but because of just keeping track of record to update it and to identify efficiently Edmx did'nt add it

Comment: @marc_s Wanting to understand how a library or framework works is a noble thing, a lot better than the "don't fight it" approach. It's understanding how/why things like this work that make us better programmers alot more than blindly using frameworks does not.

Comment: agreed with you @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum There can be scenarios where there are no primary keys like in Audit tables.What is the fix for such scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework needs a primary key to properly identify a piece of data as unique in a particular set of data. It comes down to how it looks up entities internally and giving you the best performance possible.

For example, one of the features of Entity Framework is Change Tracking, which keeps a collection of Added, Deleted, Modified, and Unchanged entities in a series of collections defined as `Dictionary<EntityKey, EntityEntry>`. To be able to effectively handle those collections, it needs a key to perform the necessary CRUD operations to those collections in a timely manner, and as a result, it needs that key.

**Update**:

There is also a collection for keyless objects as well, but it's defined as `Dictionary<object, EntityEntry>` which has horrible performance for lookups as the key would need to be cast (or unboxed if the key is a value type) for it to be usable.