# Entity Framework incorrectly naming tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a SQL database with just 3 tables: Media, Medium and Location. When I use EF 6 to add them to a problem for some reason it creates 2 medium tables with one being called medium1. I've recreated the database and project a number of times but it does the same thing, whats the issue here?

[image: EF result]

[image: SQL database diagram]

Comment: What is your approach towards EF, are you using DB, model or code first? Perhaps you could post this as well provide more context.

Comment: The reason is EF is not able to differentiate between your Location and Medium table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Rename the ID's column either from one of the table or both as **MediumId and LocationId** [Medium & Location]
EF have some more problems also:
Like [EDMX Need Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20655212/2445111)

Answer (score -1):

Original post was deleted but solution was to stop EF from pluralising table names by default e.g Plural of medium is media

Comment: Is there a way to do this, or is this a suggestion for a future modification to EF?